# SQL implement Table struct

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I have to implement a table/object like this one:

SQL> desc car.info;

- color       VARCHAR2(12)
- name        VARCHAR2(12)
- ps          NUMBER(10)

It is an Oracle Databse with sqlplus.
I already tried it with:

`CREATE infoType AS OBJECT(...)/`

`CREATE TABLE car(info infoType);`

But with `SQL> desc car.info;` I get: Object is not existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you need the output of describe for?

you can call describe for the table: `desc cars`, and you can call describe for the type `desc infoType`

if you need the information about all "type" columns at once you can select it from dictionary views `user_tab_cols`  and `user_type_attrs`:

```
select table_name, column_name , data_type, attr_name, attr_type_name
from 
    user_tab_cols
    left outer join user_type_attrs 
    on(data_type = type_name)
where table_name = 'CAR'
;
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I got a text file which describes the database and there he use the command **SQL> desc car.info;** therefore its possible...

Comment: @MathiasHölzl desc car.info means table **info** from the user **car** and not the column info from the table car